# Why do I have to access software through a folder rather than in the dash?

Tags: 12.04, unity, unity-dash, blender

In this case, the software is Blender. I followed the instructions on Blender.org, and it all works. But, when I click on Blender in the dash, it runs version 2.62, which is what I got with apt-get. If I want the latest version that I downloaded from the website (2.68a), I have to go into the folder that was extracted from the .tar.bz2 file and click on Blender in there. Isn't there a way to connect the icon in the dash with the last one I downloaded, so I don't have to keep going through the file system?

Answer (score 3):

You have to create a new file in `~/.local/share/applications` called `blender.desktop` with the following content inside:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Blender
GenericName=3D modeller
Comment=3D modeling, animation, rendering and post-production
Exec=/path/to/bleder-version-2.68a
Icon=blender
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Graphics;3DGraphics;
MimeType=application/x-blender;
```

Change `/path/to/bleder-version-2.68a` with the absolute path of Blender, version 2.68a.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using the `.desktop` file that was installed in the system. If you want to use another blender, you should either:

1. Remove the Blender installed with apt and create the `.desktop` file
2. Modify the current `.desktop` file
3. Create another `.desktop` file with different name.

You should look into `/usr/share/applications/*.desktop` for them. Create a file with `root` and save it. You can read a extensive guide about desktop entries here

[How can I edit/create new launcher items in Unity by hand?](https://askubuntu.com/q/13758/169736)

Comment: He doesn't need to remove the Blender installed with apt. Maybe other users from the system wants to access that version.

Comment: I put 3 possible action paths. If he doesn't want to remove it, then look for 2 or 3 ;)

Comment: Yes, you have right, but that's not clear enough. I read those 3 possible action paths as 3 steps to follow.